# Limit of a Logarithmic Function

Tags: limits, logarithms

Consider a function $f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \mathrm{log}_T(x^a+x^b)$ for $x>1$ and $a,b$ are real numbers satisfying $a>b$. Find:

1. $\lim_{x \to 1+} \mathrm{log}_x(x^a+x^b)$
2. $\lim_{x \to \infty} \mathrm{log}_x(x^a+x^b)$

For the first part, I tried writing converting it to natural logarithm and then apply the limit. But it just diverges. Not sure if it is correct.

$\mathrm{log}_x(x^a+x^b)=\frac{\ln(x^a+x^b)}{\ln x}$.

The numerator tends to $\ln 2$ but the denominator tends to 0.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: for the first part the answer is $+\infty$.

For the second part you have to consider various cases. For example, if $a>b>0$, then you can apply L'Hopital's Rule to get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {ax^{a}+bx^{b}} {x^{a}+x^{b}}$. Divide numerator and denominator by $x^{a}$ to see that the limit is $a$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this. So after that, I need to consider two more cases: b<a<0 and b<0<a?

Comment: @MakVish Yes, that is right.

Comment: For y<0<x, I am getting the same answer as I can still apply L'Hospital's rule. The final answer is x. I am confused about the last case: 0>x>y where L'Hospital rule doesn't help I guess.

Comment: @MakVish In your comment you are writng $x,y$ for $a,b$. I suppose your confusion is with the case $0>a>b$. In this case apply L'Hoapital's Rule as before and then divide all the terms by $x^{b}$ instead of dividing by $x^{a}$; you will get the limit as $a$.

Comment: You mean the final limit will be $b$ for the case $0>a>b$ right?

Comment: @MakVish The limit is $a$. $\frac {ax^{a-b}+b} {x^{a-b}+1} \to a$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Oh, yes got it. Thanks!